# W3C validation - unable to pass arrays in href

Tags: arrays, href, w3c-validation

I am using w3c validator with html5. I have an array `afilter[]=abc` I am passing in the href and I have tried escaping the brackets as follows:

```
<a href='slideshowform.php?x=y&amp;afilter&#91;&#93;=abc'>phases of matter</a>
```

But I am still getting the error:

```
 Bad value slideshowform.php?x=y&afilter[]=abc for attribute href on element a: Illegal character in query component.
```

How can I pass an array without getting errors - or did I escape the brackets incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to URL encode it, not HTML encode it. Your URL would have to look like the following:

```
slideshowform.php?x=y&afilter%5B%5D=abc
```

Most programming languages have stuff like this built in (e.g. [`rawurlencode()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) or [`encodeURI` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI)) or you can simply use an online service like (no affiliation, just one of the first search results) http://www.url-encode-decode.com/

Of course it’s a good idea to encode the HTML reserved characters for outputting the link in an HTML document as well. So you’d end up with the following URL within your HTML document.

```
slideshowform.php?x=y&amp;afilter%5B%5D=abc
```

Comment: Got it. I thought hex representations of characters were valid in a url, but apparently not. I have been using urlencode for any user data that might end up in a url (e.g. search string) and running all my href links through htmlspecialchars. Seems like all I have to do is replace [] with `urlencode('[]')`.  Thanks for the clarification.